# How to List.sum a List (Maybe Float)?

Tags: list, elm

I am trying to convert strings to floats and find their sum:

```elm
> String.split "," "0.2,0.3,3.1" 
> List.map String.toFloat ["0.2","0.3","3.1"]
> List.sum [Just 0.2,Just 0.3,Just 3.1]
```

But I'm getting these compiler messages:

```
This argument is a list of type:

    List (Maybe Float)

But `sum` needs the 1st argument to be:

    List number

Hint: Use Maybe.withDefault to handle possible errors. Longer term, it is
usually better to write out the full `case` though!
```

How can I get the sum of these values?

Answer (score 6):

You have created a `List (Maybe Float)`, but you need a `List Float` (`number` is a special type which can be either `Int` or `Float`).  This means that you need to handle the case when the value in the list is `Nothing`.  The error message suggests using `Maybe.withDefault`, which would look something like this:

```
"0.2,0.3,3.1"
|> String.split ","
|> List.map String.toFloat
|> List.map (Maybe.withDefault 0)
|> List.sum
```

Alternatively, [`List.filterMap`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/List#filterMap) is designed to take a function which returns a `Maybe` and remove `Nothing` values.  In this case, `String.toFloat` is that kind of function, so you could to this instead:

```
"0.2,0.3,3.1"
|> String.split ","
|> List.filterMap String.toFloat
|> List.sum
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message points out, you need to handle the `Nothing` case. Assuming you simply want to discard those values, you can run your list through `List.filterMap`.

```elm
> l = [Just 0.2,Just 0.3,Just 3.1,Nothing]
[Just 0.2,Just 0.3,Just 3.1]
    : List (Maybe Float)
> List.filterMap identity l |> List.sum
3.6 : Float
```

You can compose a function to reuse your logic:

```
> justSum = List.filterMap identity >> List.sum
<function> : List (Maybe number) -> number
> justSum l
3.6 : Float
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.toFloat` returns `Nothing` when the string is not a valid float. You need to decide what happens when you have a string like this:

```
"0.2,0.3,3.1,h"
```

Because it contains `h` which is not a number, running `String.split ","` then `List.map String.toFloat` will produce this result:

```
[Just 0.2, Just 0.3, Just 3.1, Nothing]
```

Other answers suggest that you use `List.filterMap` to ignore the invalid strings. But if you instead want the sum to be `Nothing` if any strings are invalid, you can use [`Maybe.Extra.combine`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/latest/Maybe-Extra#combine) like this:

```
import Maybe.Extra

"0.2,0.3,3.1"
  |> String.split ","
  |> List.map String.toFloat
  |> Maybe.Extra.combine
  |> Maybe.map List.sum
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following function:

```
sumMaybes : List (Maybe number) -> Maybe number
sumMaybes = List.foldl (Maybe.map2 (+)) (Just 0)

-- examples

sumMaybes [Just 1, Just 2] == Just 3
sumMaybes [Nothing, Just 2] == Nothing
sumMaybes [] = Just 0
```

Comment: Nice. I suspect `List.foldl` does short circuit on the first `Nothing` value  but I'm not sure. If I want to short circuit, should I use `Mabye-Extra.combine` or something else?